# Redirect only a specific type of URL to a new subdomain

Tags: redirect, webserver

right now we have thousands of links to documents in customer emails with this structure:

[www.website.com/document/123456](http://www.website.com/document/123456)

I would like any link above to redirect to app.website.com/document/123456

Comment: you need to tell us how? apache, nginx, dns, php, js, java?

Comment: nginx. I imagine this is a .htaccess solution

Comment: if you want an implementation on your server that's running apache you would do it in htaccess. if you're running nginx as your web server you would most likely do it in nginx.conf. Do you have nginx or apache on your server(s)?